# Delete unused panels

Tags: panel, appframework, jqmobi

Is there a "right" way to delete panels that I will no longer use from a mobile app that uses Intel's App Framework UI? Or it is enough to delete the panel divs from the DOM? I want to do this because the main page is turning big, making the app run slower, and maybe I can free some resources by doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just removing the `.panel` DIVs from the DOM should be OK using `$().remove()`.

Just make sure that there is no `href` reference to the `.panel`.

You may also want to do `$.ui.clearHistory()` so that all back navigation is cleared.